# Android - App isn't installed

Tags: android, permissions

Hi and hope someone can help,

I'm doing a course and they're testing us on Android permissions and the task we currently have is to have 2 packages, one of which can call up the other package, I'll call these the Calling Package and the Called Package.

There is nothing at all special in the Called Package, a very straightforward method which merely loads a very straightforward layout file so all the tailoring of permissions is done within the Manifest file.

My problem is that, 
a) My Calling app seems to work fine i.e. it calls up the Called app and everything seems to work fine. No issues to report in the LogCat
b) However, if I try and start my Called app directly from the apps loaded onto either an emulator or real device I get a message saying "App isn't installed" again  nothing appears in the LogCat

So I'm enclosing the manifest file for the Called app and you'll spot the //TODO sections where my code strays from the file that I've been supplied with.

My thanks for your interest, here's the Called app's Manifest file which is where the bug must be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.dangerousapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!--
      TODO - Using a permission element,
      define a custom permission with name
          "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" 
      and "dangerous" protection level.
-->
<permission
    android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
    android:description="@string/permission_description"
    android:label="@string/permission_label"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" >
</permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- TODO - enforce the custom permission on this Activity -->

    <activity
        android:name=".DangerousActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" >

        <!--
             TODO - add additional intent filter info so that this Activity
              will respond to an Implicit Intent with the action
              "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"
        -->

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

`MainActivity` cannot be started by the home screen launcher, because the home screen does not hold the `course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM` permission, and you are defending that activity with that permission.

Comment: Great, thanks so does that mean I need to add something extra to the intent-filter?

Comment: @RogerW: No, it means you have to remove that permission from the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity. Either have a separate `LAUNCHER` activity, or remove the permission entirely.